# Помогите понять содержимое ORACLE DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

[image: DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY]
Вывод всего содержимого DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY выглядит след. образом:

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно, чем Вы выводите. Явный сбой форматирования, кроме того в размётке пропущен столбец bundle_series, а его данные выведены. Правильно читать это так:

```
строка 1
action time = 22.09.11 20:04:47.707619
action = apply
namespace = server
version = 11.2.0.3.0
bundle series = psu
comments = PatchSet 11.2.0.2.0
```

и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо. А что означает apply? - Запуск сервера? Применение обновления?

Comment: Применение. Т.е. в данном случае применение патча на сервер (это указано в столбце namespace).

Comment: Вот ссылка на описание представления и что какой столбец означает: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4057.htm#REFRN23549

Comment: Спасибо. Этот источник я уже смотрел, мне было непонятно что такое apply. Что понимается под "применением"? Чем upgrade отличается от apply? Что понимается под downgrade? Почему здесь есть bundle_series а в источнике нет? Что значит bundle_series? Что такое PSU? Если скинете ссылку на ресурс где можно это узнать, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Потому что мы смотрели описание для старой версии. Столбец BUNDLE_SERIES появился с 11.2 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_4212.htm#REFRN23549. Полагаю, apply - это применение патча, не меняющего версию, upgrade и так ясно, downgrade - иногда версию надо понизить из-за критичных для системы ошибок в более новой.